# About Goldbach's conjecture : a certain differential equation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

This question is related to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61842/about-goldbachs-conjecture

Let  $ y(x) $  be a function such that  $ \alpha_{n}=O(y(n)) $ . taking  $ y(x) : =x^{1/2}\log^{2} x $  leads to  $ y'=\dfrac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}\log^{2}x+2x^{-1/2}\log x $ . As  $1/ \log x $ is roughly equal to  $ \pi(x)/x $ , is there any reason to believe that  $ \alpha_{n}=O(z(n)) $  where the function  $ z(x) $ fulfills the differential equation  $ z'=\dfrac{z}{2\Delta}+z\dfrac{\pi(x+\Delta)-\pi(x-\Delta)}{\Delta} $ where  $ \Delta : =\Delta(x) $  is such that $ \Delta(x)\leq (1+o(1))x $?

Comment: why ?  ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Because. In case you wouldn't have noticed, I think induction can be used in mathematics to lead to discovery.

Comment: Goldbach is extremely complicated to analyze. You didn't define $\alpha_n$. Your differential equation is a mess : do you really think we can do anything better than replacing $\pi(x+a)-\pi(x)$ by [$\frac{a}{\ln x} + O(a^\theta)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) and "hope" it will give something acceptable ?

Comment: $ \alpha_{n} $ is an error term defined in the link I gave.

Comment: In a more rigorous setting, one can consider the sequence of differential equations  $ y'_{k}=\dfrac{y_{k}}{2x^{1-1/k}}+y_{k}\dfrac{\pi(x+x^{1-1/k})-\pi(x-x^{1-1/k})}{x^{1-1/k}} $ and then take the limit as  $ k $  tends to  $ \infty $ .